# Apache2 no longer accessible beyond localhost after working with flask

Tags: heroku, flask, apache2

I have just begun working with flask and deploying a website to Heroku. Suddenly I realized that my apache2 server on the same server is not accessible beyond localhost anymore even though it had been accessible within my local network prior to this. Has flask been known to interfere with apache?

Comment: If you used 127.0.0.1 in an Apache config, that'll restrict visibility to the local host, which is not at all what you want if you're using heroku.

Comment: Thanks. I looked through 000-default.conf & apache2.conf and didn't find 127.0.0.1. Am I missing another place I should look? As I said, I was getting access beyond the localhost before I started working with heroku. I haven't changed any configuration so I'm trying to sort out why I would have suddenly lost access.

Comment: Post your configs